# Is this a Bot modifying my URLs for some tracking purpose?

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, sql-injection

I don't know if this is bad code on our part, or a bot/spider doing something for tracking purposes. What I'm seeing is our URLs are getting modified, and it's generating site errors and error emails that I'm set up to get when it seems like my site is being hacked.

For example, a URL that should read/load like this

```
http://site.com/page.asp?pid=915411&order=Date
```

gets loaded like this

```
http://site.com/page.asp?pid=-1'&order=Date
```

the email I get shows

```
query string = pid=-1%27&order=Date
```

The IP address that comes up in the error emails always change, but many point to Kiev or Minsk, but are so varied I don't see how I can stop this from happening easily. My site is on an IIS 7.5 server, win2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone is trying to hack your application. They are testing if your application uses values from the forms or URL directly into SQL statements.

This hacking attempt is easy and called "SQL injection". Check your application if it is vulnerable, fix it immediately if required.

Additionally, try to track the attackers and if you see them coming from a set of IP addresses, block them.

Answer (score 0):

Using HTTP_REEFER we are able to control the URL Modifying on directly.
Try the below code

```
if Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER") = "" Then  
    RESPONSE.WRITE  " <b><h1><font color=blue></font><font color=red>UNSECURED MENU ACCESS</font><font color=blue></font><h1></b> "
response.end
End if
```